# "friends of friends" like sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building an application where users can connect with each other (something like friends in any social network).

I am saving that connections in a table with the following structure:

```
id_user1 | id_user2 | is_accepted | is_blocked | created_at
```

The connections between users are bi-directional, so when two users are connected there is only one record in the table. Doesnt matter if the `user_id` is in `id_user1` or `id_user2` collumn.

Now i need to write a sql query to get "friends of friends" of a certain user that are not already friends of the user.
Also the user must be accepted and not blocked.

In resume, here are the steps i need to execute.

1. Find all the users id associated with the user I want (`id_user1 = current_user` or `id_user2 = current_user` and `is_accepted` and `!blocked`)
2. foreach of the returned user_ids --> get all the associated users( ignore associations with  current user) (make sure it is `accepted` and `!blocked` also).

How can I do such query?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you really want this table to be bi-directional. What if A blocks B but B still wants to hear from A? Not to mention, ff you do that, then doing the self-join will be much easier.

Comment: I think if A blocks B, not only he don't want to hear from B, but don't want B to hear from him.

Comment: If you want to go upto one level, then self join will do ... If you want to go more then one level, then i guess Hierarchical queries are better, however i am not sure how to achieve that in MySQL.

Comment: @Andre: It is not uncommon in social networks when one person makes someone his/her friend but the other person doesn't do the same, so I would rather agree with @drysdam.

Comment: @Andriy I'm not saying that that it's wrong or bad. It may just not be the requirement.

Comment: Well, Andre is right. thats the way my app work. Because the connections are bi-directional when a user blocks another both users can´t see the other. But this is not really important for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE f2.id_user1 WHEN CASE f1.id_user1 WHEN $user THEN f1.id_user2 ELSE f1.id_user1 END THEN f2.id_user2 ELSE f2.id_user1 END
FROM    friends f1
JOIN    friends f2
ON      f2.id_user1 = CASE f1.id_user1 WHEN $user THEN f1.id_user2 ELSE f1.id_user1 END
        OR f2.id_user2 = CASE f1.id_user1 WHEN $user THEN f1.id_user2 ELSE f1.id_user1 END
WHERE   (f1.id_user1 = $user OR f1.id_user = $user)
        AND f1.is_accepted = 1
        AND f2.is_accepted = 1
        AND f1.is_blocked = 0
        AND f2.is_blocked = 0
        AND NOT (f1.id_user1, f1.id_user2) = (f2.id_user1, f2.id_user2)
```

Note that it is better to store the users least first, greatest second. In this case the query would be more simple.

Answer (score 4):

For the reasons others have mentioned, and because I've seen it work better in other systems, I'd go with a row for each direction.

```
primary_user_id | related_user_id | is_accepted | is_blocked | created_at
```

You can also then create a clustered index on the user_id which should more than offset the overhead of doubling the number of rows.

Your first query would then translate into something like this:

```
SELECT f1.related_user_id
FROM friends f1
WHERE f1.primary_user_id = @current_user
AND f1.is_accepted = 1 AND f1.is_blocked = 0
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM friends f2
  WHERE f1.related_user_id = f2.primary_user_id
  AND f2.related_user_id = @current_user
  AND f2.is_accepted = 1 AND f2.is_blocked = 0
```

Not sure if you can do table functions in MySql. If so then wrap this up into a function to make your second query simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When working with the one-record-per-friendship table directly, all queries will be bloated and error-prone, because you will have to write 'id_user1 = ... or id_user2 = ...' often. I'd create a view

```
CREATE VIEW bidifreinds (id_user1, id_user2, is_accepted, is_blocked, created_at) AS
SELECT id_user1, id_user2, is_accepted, is_blocked, created_at FROM friends
UNION
SELECT id_user2, id_user1, is_accepted, is_blocked, created_at FROM friends
```

This will make life much easier.

Then you can write

```
SELECT f1.id_user1, f2.id_user2
FROM friends f1, friends f2
WHERE f2.id_user1 = f1.id_user2
  AND f1.is_accepted
  AND NOT f1.is_blocked
  AND f2.is_accepted
  AND NOT f2.is_blocked
```

And I hope you're not usind MySQL, because MySQL is very slow at querying over views.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_user1 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user2 in    
(select id_user1 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user2 = :a_user: 
    union 
    select id_user2 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user1 = :a_user:)
union
select id_user2 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user1 in
(select id_user1 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user2 = :a_user: 
    union 
    select id_user2 from friends where is_accepted = 1 and is_blocked = 0 and id_user1 = :a_user:)
```

You can add a whereClause to weed out :a_user: from the resultset.